# Lecture note recommendations for the endogenous growth model (EGM)

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm curious if anyone has a recommended lecture notes, slides, or book, anything really, that goes through evolutions of basic models like $y=AK$, to $y=AK^aL^{1-a}$, to $y_t=A_tK_t$, to $y_t=A_tK^{a}_tL_t^{1-a}$, etc. such that the models get more complex. I'm following along with the lectures in class but all the asides, comments on real-world examples, aren't helping me solidify the intuition for the big-ideas that are underlying some of the evolutions. Basically, why some models are too simple, and what adding more variables does to the model.

Previous threads focus on discrete models in econometrics (hit markets for ideas I'm concerned with lead me here), so not that relevant.

Comment: Could you please state at which level you are studying/want to study? Undergrad, Masters, PhD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the notes closely resembling what you are looking for - a gradual explanation of how the growth theories develop - are those from Acemoglu. Check his web page for slides and look in your school library for Intro to Modern Economic Growth. The slides are very detailed I think.

Growth models are, I believe, presented very rigorously. Additionally, in my opinion, it is discussed how they are connected.